# Python and Selenium pulls up a dialog box instead of the automatic download I get when I manually click on link

Tags: python, excel, selenium-webdriver, download

I'm using Python to access the SEC's website for 10-K downloadable spreadsheets. I created code that requests user input for a Stock Ticker Symbol, successfully opens Firefox, accesses the Edgar search page at https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html, and inputs the correct ticker symbol. The problem is downloading the spreadsheet automatically and saving it.

Right now, I can manually click on "View Excel Spreadsheet", and the spreadsheet automatically downloads. But when I run my Python code, I get a dialog box from Firefox. I've set Firefox to automatically download, I've tried using 'find_element_by_xpath', 'find_element_by_css_selector' and both do not work to simply download the file. Both those methods merely call up the same dialog box.  I tried 'find_element_by_link_text' and got an error message about not being able to find "view Excel Spreadsheet". My example ticker symbol was CAT for Caterpillar (NYSE: CAT).  My code is below:

```
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from pathlib import Path
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import time

ticker = input("please provide a ticker symbol: ")

# can do this other ways, but will create a function to do this 
def get_edgar_results(ticker):
        url = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=" + str(ticker) + "&type=10-k&dateb=20200501&count=20"

# define variable that opens Firefox via my executable path for geckodriver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\geckodriver.exe")

 # timers to wait for the webpage to open and display the page itself
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver,40)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(40)
    driver.get(url)

    # timers to have page wait for the page to load.
    # seemed that the total amount of time was necessary; not sure about these additional lines
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(50)
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
    time.sleep(30)

    # actual code to search the resulting page for the button to click and access the excel document for download
    annual_links = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="interactiveDataBtn"]')
    annual_links.click()

    # need to download the excel spreadsheet itself in the "financial report"
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(50)
    wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 50)

    excel_sheet = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/a[2]')
    excel_sheet.click()
    # i'm setting the resulting dialog box to open and download automatically from now on. if i want to change it back
    # i'll need to use this page:  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file
    # Testing showed that dialog box "open as" probably suits my needs better than 'save'.

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()


get_edgar_results(ticker)
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much a recommendation based on your actual code, or how Selenium works, but more general advice when trying to gather information from the web.

Given the opportunity, accessing a website through its API is far more friendly to programming than attempting the same task through Selenium. When you use Selenium for webscraping, very often the websites do not behave in the same way they do when accessed through a normal browser. This could be for any number of reasons, not thee least of which could be websites intentionally preventing automated browsers like Selenium from accessing them.

In this case, [EDGAR SEC provides an HTTPS access service](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/accessing-edgar-data.htm) through which you should be able to get the information you're looking for.

Without digging too deeply into this data, it should not be tremendously difficult to instead request this information with an http request library like `requests`, and save it that way.

```
import requests

result = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/18230/000001823020000214/Financial_Report.xlsx")

with open("file.xlsx", "wb") as excelFile:
    excelFile.write(result.content)
```

The only difficulty comes with getting the stock ticker's CIK to build the above URL, but that shouldn't be too hard with the same API information.

The EDGAR website fairly transparently exposes you to its data through its URLs. You can bypass all the Selenium weirdness and instead just build the URL, and request the information directly without loading all the JavaScript, etc.

EDIT: You can also browse through this information in a more programmatic fashion, too. The link above mentions that each directory within edgar/full-index also provides a JSON file, which is easily computer-readable. So you could request `https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/index.json`, parse out the year you want, request that year, parse out the quarter you want, request that quarter, then parse out the company you want, and request that company's information, etc.

For instance, to get the CIK number of Caterpillar, you would get and parse thee `company.gz` file from `https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2020/QTR4.json`, parse it into a dataframe, find the line with `CATERPILLAR INC` on it, find the CIK and accession numbers from the associated .txt file, and then find the right URL to download their Excel file. A bit circuitous, but if you can work out a way to just skip to the CIK number you can cut down on the number of requests needed.

Comment: I'll first admit I'm not a skilled programmer at all. I'm definitely a novice. Having said that, what I'm trying to do overall is download all approximately 6000-10000 publicly traded stock spreadsheets, The code you see is written to make the problem easy for me to download one at a time. The code you suggested didn't work in PyCharm, but maybe that's because I left out a key line of code? I'll mention that I wanted an API approach, but I didnt understand XBRL well enough to know what will give me a manipulateable excel file to modify/parse for all 10,000 stocks. I've already tried Intrinio.

Comment: So essentially: download this file: ‘’’ https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2020/QTR4.json’’’. In that file are all the stocks by name. Get their CIK and accession numbers. Then put them in this form: “ https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/TICKER/ACCESSION/Financial_Report.xlsx”. and loop through your chosen stocks, replacing TICKER and ACCESSION as needed.

Comment: To clarify, I mean you need to get the “company.gz” file from “ https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2020/QTR4”. Parse that data file until you get the company names you want, and then programmatically inject them into the url format I mentioned in the previous comment. 

Using selenium to download so many files will take an extremely long time. Downloading them by URL is dramatically more efficient and likely easier.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I knew I was headed down a long path with Selenium and interacting with a browser. It just wasn't obvious to me at first that [requests] was the way to go, as well as for what [requests] should pull. I hope this comes with more experience.  Your code helped tremendously. I upvoted your answer, but I don't have enough reputation. .

Comment: Not a problem. I think using requests should be the way forward, since all you need is the CIK to then pull a list of all filings, then just go through the filings and find the excel files. The only difficult part will be getting a list of CIKs, but I would imagine you’ve got something in mind already.

Comment: I might have spoke too soon. You're right, I have an easy method to get CIKs for all 10,000 stocks or so. But it turns out that the Accession numbers for the individual 10-K spreadsheets does not follow the SECs stated convention on how to build the accession number. Accession numbers aren't quite arbitrary, but It looks like there are dozens of exceptions as listed in the link for "Acc-no" in " https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0000106535&type=10-K&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=40&search_text=    . I'd love your thoughts on how to proceed

Comment: And it turns out that I cannot use wildcards like https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/106535/000??????????????/Financial_Report.xlsx   in place of the accession number. I'm trying to avoid the webscaping/selenium approach, but this accession number issue is a challenge.

Comment: The method forward is to access a specific CIK, e.g. https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/106535/index.json. Which then gives you a list of all accession numbers relevant to that CIK. Then you just tack that accession number on, check if the resulting index.json has an excel file listed, and move on from there.

Comment: Check [my github repo](https://github.com/Catradora/STACKOVERFLOW/blob/refactor/edgar.py) for some sample code that should get you on your way. I recommend heavily limiting the time period, or else it'll take quite a while to download all the listings.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much. The github code was really helpful. But even better, you mentioning this is a challenging problem was helpful. I've gone through the github code and now need to sort the resulting 8-Ks, 10-Qs, and 10-Ks links into separate folders or columns.

Comment: Of course! The SEC does not make it terribly easy to filter down results no matter how you split. Glad I could be of assistance! Don't be afraid to reach out with questions

Comment: Yikes. I have tons of questions so I'll take you up on your offer.  I've tried taking the next step I mentioned which is creating folders by CIK number for each spreadsheet link, accession number, and downloaded spreadsheets.I already tried this with no success https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324146/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-path   For example in your github code, you'd have a folder labeled ""0000320193" and within the folder there would be 6 downloaded spreadsheets in it, the next folder is  "0000018230" with 5 downloaded spreadsheets in it, and so on.

Comment: Catradora, is there any way I can contact you about this?