# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'path'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying incrementally to build a financial statement database. The first steps center around collecting 10-Ks from the SEC's EDGAR database. I have code for pulling the relevant 8-Ks, 10-Ks, and 10-Qs by CIK number and accession number, and retrieving the relevant excel spreadsheet. The code below is now centering on trying to create a folder within a directory, then name the folder with the CIK code, then pull the spreadsheet from the EDGAR database, and save the spreadsheet to the folder with the CIK code. My example is a csv file I'm calling "accessionnumtest.csv", which has headings:

company_name,report_type,cik,date,cik_accession

and data:

4Less Group, Inc.,10K/A,1438901,11/27/2019,edgar/data/1438901/000121390019024801.txt

AB INTERNATIONAL GROUP CORP.,10K,1605331,10/22/2019,edgar/data/1605331/000166357719000384.txt

ABM INDUSTRIES INC /DE/,10K,771497,12/20/2019,edgar/data/771497/000162828019015259.txt

ACTUANT CORP,10K,6955,10/29/2019,edgar/data/6955/000000695519000033.txt

my code is below

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = os.getcwd()

folder_path = "C:/metricdatadb/"

df = pd.read_csv("accessionnumtest.csv")

folder_name = df['cik']
print(folder_name)

for row in df.iterrows():
    dir = df.path.join(folder_path, folder_name)
    os.makedirs(dir)
```

This code is giving me, AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'path' error. I have renamed the path, checked for whitespace in the headers.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the error: `os.path.join`. Not `pd.path.join`. You are calling the wrong module.

That being said, your code is not doing what you are trying to do regardless of the error. `folder_name` will not update for each row. You could do `row.cik` to get the value for each `iterrows()`

```
dir = os.path.join(folder_path, row.cik)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is relatively unclear what you're working towards accomplishing, particularly with .csv files and Pandas. The code you have seems to have a lot of curious errors in it, which I think might be ameliorated by going back to learn some of the more simple Python concepts before trying something as difficult as web-scraping. Note I don't mean to give up, rather than building up the fundamentals is a necessary step in this type of project.

That said, if I'm understanding your intent correctly, you want to create a file hierarchy for 10-K, 10-Q, etc. filings for several CIKs.

There shouldn't be any need to use .csv files, or pandas for this.

Probably the simplest way to do this would be to do it in the same step you download them.

Pseudocode for this would be as follows:

```
for cik in list_of_ciks:
     first_file = find_first_file_online();

     if first_file is 10-K:
          save_to_10-K folder for CIK
     if first_file is 10-Q:
          save_to_10-Q folder for CIK
```

As I said above, you can skip the .csv file (Also, note that CSV stands for "comma-separated-value." Some of the entries in your data contain commas, e.g. "4Less Group, Inc." This is incompatible with a CSV file, as it will split the single entry into two columns on the comma, shifting all of your data one column).

When you process the data, you'll want to build the folders as you go.

When you iterate through a new CIK, create the master folder for that CIK. When you encounter a 10-K, create a folder for 10-K's and save it with a unique name. Since you need to use the accession numbers to get the excel sheets, that wouldn't be a bad naming convention to follow.

It would be something like this:

```
import requests
import pathlib

cik_list = [cik_1, cik_2... cik_n]

for cik in cik_list:
     file = requests.get("cik/accession/Report.xlsx").data

     with open(pathlib.Path(cik, report_type, accession_number + ".xlsx", "wb")) as excel_file:
     excel_file.write(file.data)
```

The above code will definitely not run, and does not include everything you would need to make it work, since that information has been written by you. Integrating the above concepts into your code is up to you.

To reiterate, you have the CIK, the accession number, and the report type. To save the files in folders, you need only create the folders as you go, with the form "CIK/report_type/accession.xlsx"

Comment: Catradora, is there any way I can contact you about this?

Comment: We should try and answer this question publicly, so people with a similar issue in the future can find the answer. 

I think we’re missing some pieces of the puzzle. Can you edit your question with more of your code and a better explanation of what you want to do and why, and we can go from there?

Comment: Fair enough. I'm realizing that my programming skills aren't where they need to be if I'm going to succeed with my project in the timeline i've allotted. This programming task was appproximately 2% of a bigger effort that should take only a an hour or two, and I'm struggling with it for a week now. I can't seem to break the entire effort down to get the simple help I thought I'd need to make it through the entire project. I'm starting to think that I'll need to hire a skilled developer to do the entire thing if I want my project done in the next few months. Thanks again Catradora for your help